# Limiting user selections with mobiscroll 2.5.0

Tags: date, sencha-touch-2

I am using this library: mobiscroll.custom-2.5.0.min.js. How do I set limits to deny users' selecting past dates?

My code:

```
xtype:'panel',
layout:'hbox',
            width: (screenWidth-(84+24+55))/2,
            cls: 'paymentsSectionDetailsDate',
            items:[{
             xtype:'panel',
             html:'<div class="paymentsSectionDetailsDateLabel" >'+txt_PayOn+'</div>',
             width: 80
             },{
             xtype: 'button',
             text:txt_select_date,
             name: 'BillPayDetailsForm_date',
             id:'BillPayDetailsForm_date',
             cls: 'paymentsSectionDetailsDateTextButt',
             listeners:{
              tap : function() 
              {
               inputNumber=4;
               $('#dateIos').fadeIn("slow");
              }
             }

            }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with mobiscroll, could you use a [datepicker](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.picker.Date)? It has 'yearFrom' and 'yearTo' configuration options. You might be able to use a listener to get the data into mobiscroll.

Comment: thank you for your answer , it is work like that var opt = {}
    opt.date = {
           preset : 'date',
              minDate: new Date(minYYYY, minMM , minDD),
              maxDate: new Date(maxYYYY, maxMM , maxDD)
          };
      
        $('#test').val('').scroller('destroy').scroller(
         $.extend(
          opt['date'], 
          { theme: 'ios', mode: 'scroller', display: 'inline', lang:'' }
         )
        );
        
        $('#test').scroller('setDate', new Date(year, month-1, day), true);